# How to pass Array Values as Separate Parameters in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftbond

I have the following code using [Bond](https://github.com/DeclarativeHub/Bond).

```
combineLatest(settings.userAutoRefreshInterval, config.value?.userRefreshInterval).observeNext { [weak self] _ in
    self?.updateAutoUserRefresh()
}.dispose(in: self.bag)
```

Of course, that has a build error since Bond's `combineLatest` doesn't accept optionals.

I have considered doing an `if let` and writing basically the same code twice, but that feels really messy.

In JavaScript, you can pass in an array with each element as a separate parameter into a function. Like the following:

```
function test(a, b, c) {
    console.log("a", a);
    console.log("b", b);
    console.log("c", c);
}

const array = ["Hello", "world", "!!!"];
test(...array);
```

Is there a way to do that in Swift?

If not, any ideas for how to get my code working and have it be as clean as possible?

Comment: Not supported yet. [This ticket](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-128) has been open for 3 years.

Comment: @Damon That function is part of Bond. I didn't create it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a tuple

```
func test(aTuple: (String, String, String)) {
    print(aTuple.0)
    print(aTuple.1)
    print(aTuple.2)
}

let theTuple = ("Hello", "world", "!!!")
test(aTuple: theTuple)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That isn't a true array tho. So at no point could I filter out the `nil`/optional results. Which is what I need to do to make that code more clean.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your arguments are the same type, then you can use `varargs` parameters:

```
func test(_ args: String...) {
    args.forEach { print $0 }
}
```

You then call it like

```
test("Life", "Liberty", "Pursuit of Happiness")
```

Comment: Ok, that looks promising, but I just realized that looks like it would require changes to Bond, and not something I could do.